# OPENGL: drawing multiple point lights

Tags: c++, opengl, lighting

I'm having an issue drawing multiple point lights in my scene. I am working on a simple maze-style game in OpenGL, where the maze is randomly generated. Each "room" in the maze is represented by a Room struct, like so:

```
struct Room
{
    int x, z;
    bool already_visited, n, s, e, w;
    GLuint vertex_buffer, texture, uv_buffer, normal_buffer;
    std::vector<glm::vec3>vertices, normals;
    std::vector<glm::vec2>uvs;
    glm::vec3 light_pos; //Stores the position of a light in the room
};
```

Each room has a light in it, the position of this light is stored in `light_pos`. This light is used in a simple per-vertex shader, like so:

```
layout(location = 0) in vec3 pos;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 uv_coords;
layout(location = 2) in vec3 normal;
uniform mat4 mvpMatrix;
uniform mat4 mvMatrix;
uniform vec3 lightpos;
out vec2 vs_uv;
out vec3 vs_normal;
out vec3 color;
void main()
{
    gl_Position = mvpMatrix * vec4(pos,1.0);
    vs_normal = normal;
    vs_uv = uv_coords;
    vec3 lightVector = normalize(lightpos - pos);
    float diffuse = clamp(dot(normal,lightVector),0.0,1.0);
    color = vec3(diffuse,diffuse,diffuse);
}
```

My fragment shader looks like this (ignore the "vs_normal", it is unused for now):

```
in vec2 vs_uv;
in vec3 vs_normal;
in vec3 color;
uniform sampler2D tex;
out vec4 frag_color;

void main()
{
    frag_color = vec4(color,1.0) * texture(tex,vs_uv).rgba;
}
```

And my drawing code looks like this:

```
mat4 mvMatrix = view_matrix*model_matrix;
mat4 mvpMatrix = projection_matrix * mvMatrix;
glBindVertexArray(vertexBufferObjectID);
glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
for (int x = 0; x < NUM_ROOMS_X; x++)
{
   for (int z = 0; z < NUM_ROOMS_Z; z++)
   {
      //int x = int(std::round(position.x / ROOM_SIZE_X_MAX));
      //int z = int(std::round(position.z / ROOM_SIZE_Z_MAX));
      Room rm = room_array[x][z];
      glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, rm.vertex_buffer);
      glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*) 0);

      glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, rm.uv_buffer);
      glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*) 0);

      glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, rm.normal_buffer);
      glVertexAttribPointer(2, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*) 0);

      glUniformMatrix4fv(mvpMatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &mvpMatrix[0][0]);
      glUniformMatrix4fv(mvMatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &mvMatrix[0][0]);
      glUniform3fv(light_ID, 3, &rm.light_pos[0]); //Here is where I'm setting the new light position. It looks like this is ignored

      glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
      glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, rm.texture);
      glUniform1i(texture_ID, 0);

      glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, rm.vertices.size());
   }
}
glUseProgram(0);
glBindVertexArray(0);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(2);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

However, here is what the result looks like (I've modified my drawing code to draw a box where each light is located, and I've circled the room at position (0,0)):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyWVJ.jpg

As you can see, it looks like only the light at position (0,0) affects any of the rooms on the map, the other lights are simply ignored. I know that the lights are positioned correctly, because the boxes I use to show the positions are correct. I think even though I'm setting the new `light_pos`, it isn't going through for some reason. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out my problem. I was calling this function:

```
glUniform3fv(light_ID, 3, &rm.light_pos[0]);
```

When I should have been calling this:

```
glUniform3fv(light_ID, 1, &rm.light_pos[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing that your are doing, which is not very common, is to pass the light position as a vertex attribute. Optimally, you should pass it to the shader as a uniform variable, just as you do with the matrices. But I doubt that is the problem here.

I believe your problem is that you are doing the light calculations in different spaces. The vertexes of the surfaces that you draw are in **object/model** space, while I'm guessing, your light is located at a point defined in **world** space. Try multiplying your light position by the inverse of the model matrix you are applying to the vertexes. I'm not familiar with GLM, but I figure there must be an *inverse()* function in it:

```
vec3 light_pos_object_space = inverse(model_matrix) * rm.light_pos;
glVertexAttrib3fv(light_ID, &light_pos_object_space[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I had originally defined my light_pos as a uniform, but changed it to an attribute to see if that helped. I've since changed it back in the original question. As for the different coordinate spaces, I'm not sure that that would help as the vertices that I'm drawing are already in world space. Since everything is drawn from squares, I don't perform any local object transformations, everything is in world space (vertices and light positions) and my model matrix is just the identity matrix. Since that is the case, do you know if your suggestion would help?

Comment: If you are sure that both the vertexes and the light position are in the same space (no translation/rotation/scale applied), then no. The inverse of an identity matrix is an identity matrix. 
Another thing that you could try though is to add the layout(location) qualifier to the vertex shader outputs. I've had problems with that in the past. Make sure to match them in the fragment shader. Also, if you could post you fragment shader, that would be helpful :)

Comment: Added the Fragment Shader per your request.

As for the layout qualifier, do you mean I should create a vertex array just to handle the light positions? That seems a bit limiting, as I would like to eventually be able to define an arbitrary number of lights per room. I'll give it a try though

Comment: What I meat was for you to try adding a layout() qualifier to the outs/ins of the shaders. E.g. in the VS you have "out vec2 vs_uv;", try "layout(location = 0) out vec2 vs_uv;" and then in the fragment shader "layout(location = 0) in vec2 vs_uv;" and so on for the rest. I'm suggesting this because I once had a similar problem of corrupted data in the shaders for not adding the layout qualifier. Your frag shader seems OK, btw.

Comment: I don't believe that my issue is caused by corrupted data getting to the fragment shader. After all, the fragment shader is doing its job perfectly, its getting the colors that the vertex shader sent it and adding them to the texture. Its the vertex shader that's calculating these colors incorrectly. If data corruption was a problem, than wouldn't the colors be all messed up?